# Rich text editor that acts like a source code editor

Tags: java, windows, editor

I want a free rich text editor that runs in windows, with the following features:

- italic, bold, underline
- change font size and font colour
- indent left

But the thing is, I also want a feature found in source code editors:

- the ability to collapse passages of text [such as text within { } braces]

I only have rudimentary Java knowledge, and trying to learn to extend `javax.swing.text.EditorKit` or any of the `javax.swing.text` classes is proving to be way out of my capabilities. (and of course, writing a rich text editor from scratch is DEFINITELY out of my abilities!).

Does anyone by chance know where I might get what I'm looking for?
Or, alternatively, could anyone guide me to how I might actually craft what I'm looking for with something in `javax.swing.text`?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd want such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Something like TextWrangler or Notepad++ maybe?